# How to use the camera2 class for API 21 and make the app still running for lower APIs?

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-camera2

I am a beginner in android development and I am having a problem with using android.hardware.camera2 due to that my minimum sdk is API 16. So what I want to do now is be able to use that class but at the same time I can still make sure that people who are using lower SDK can still use it.

Should I make the minimum SDK version into API 21 and just create an if else statement for the users who have a lower version? Or is there another way?

Update: I cannot import android.hardware.camera, so how I am going to use it in my if else statement (if it was the only option)?

Comment: i suggest to use `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > your requirement)` . It might be better .

Comment: Will it still work if the minimum version is 21?

Comment: actually what you want to do ? want to use camera ?

Comment: @Erika with that if-statement you check the current version with (replace `your requirement` with 21 and set it to `>=` instead) the version you check for (in this case, 21). If it is >= 21, use camera2. Else, use camera. You can set any minSDK version you want as long as there aren't libraries that require a higher version, or features that require a higher version (e.g. if you want to use OpenGL ES 3 and not support 2, you could set minSDK to 18)

Comment: yes I want to use the camera

Comment: update: I cannot use android.hardware.camera class, I cannot import it.

Comment: what is you minSdkVersion should be in gradle app?

Comment: @MohamedEmbaby it should API 16 since I also want it to run in jellybean

Comment: so why you cant import android.hardware.camera ?

Comment: @MohamedEmbaby i dont know why. it said it can't resolve symbol

Comment: can you post exactly how you import it ?

Comment: @MohamedEmbaby 

import android.hardware.camera

Comment: try to build the project and invalidate cache/ restart option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need **minSdkVersion** ≥ 21 to use camera2 API. You don't even need to set **targetSdkVersion**. All you need is that **compileSdkVersion** be ≥ 21 (it's good practice to use the latest API available at development time).

Since your min API is > 4, you can simply use the new **camera2** API in blocks under `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)`. This is the common accepted practice for Android, event though some software purists would insist on run-time checks for the presence of `android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager` class.

You should isolate the code that uses the *deprecated* Camera API, and mark these methods with annotations `@TargetApi(16)` or `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`.